# Mysql - Join Same Rows with null entries

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I have mysql table with format like this

```
Name - Date1 - Date2
```

After I got result

```
A - NULL - 1
A - 2 - NULL
```

I want to join these results as

```
A - 2 - 1
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Will there always be exactly two rows per name with exactly that arrangement of NULL and non-NULL values?

Comment: Globally... there can be A - NULL - 1 | A - 2 - NULL | B - 1 - NULL | B - NULL - 2... This can never happen: A - 2 - 2 (only after join - so this is my goal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT Name,
         MAX(Date1),
         MAX(Date2)
    FROM tbl
GROUP BY Name
```